# Add and Compare Date and Time in HQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, datetime, hql

I had created below sql query for my code, I need to convert it to HQL createQuery, I tried a lot. Anyone please tell me how to add datetime to query itself and comparing.

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from schedule s
    where NOW() >= ADDDATE(s.view_datetime, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)");
```

Comment: HQL doesn't really support database specific date functions (since they are usually different for each DB).  But, you could run the above as a raw MySQL query from your Java code.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. it is working but i need to handle with hql. Is there any other possibility, any other solution for this?

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you obtain `NOW()` as a UNIX timestamp, you could compare that to the same value with 7200 seconds added to it.  UNIX timestamps are just numbers, and comparing them has to work.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen i will try it out.

Comment: How to Convert output of sqlquery list to java object(output of createQuery().list and createSQLQuery().list is different)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After many workaround I got answer. It may help others who searching for similar senario..

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(new Date());       
Date today = calendar.getTime(); 

Query query = session.createQuery("from schedule s where DATE(s.view_datetime) <= :today AND (hour(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - s.view_datetime) >= 2)");
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to work on Hibernate. the hour function some of the times returns NULL.. probably because you are not allowed to apply HOUR function on the diff of 2 dates, but only on a qualified date. Some more info can be found here: https://shekhargulati.com/2010/04/18/hql-which-gives-no-of-hours-bw-two-timestamps/ (please note this post is also wrong on its solution)..